# Using additional arguments in a R function inside purrr::map_df have no effect

Tags: r, function, ellipse

I have a function that performs several statistical tests (default is wilcoxon rank sum test) and returns a dataframe where each row is a result.

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

calculate_pval <- function(df, xvar, yvars, test = wilcox_test, ...){
  stat_test <- yvars %>%
    map(rlang::sym) %>%
    map(\(y) rlang::inject(!! y ~ !! rlang::ensym(xvar))) %>%
    map_df(~ test(.x, ..., data = df))
  
  return (stat_test)
}
```

I tried to have the option to add additional parameters to the statistical test (e.g., `alternative`). However, this seems to have no effect:

```
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth
```

```
> df %>% wilcox_test(len ~ supp)
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p
* <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 len   OJ     VC        30    30      576. 0.0645
```

```
> df %>% wilcox_test(len ~ supp, alternative = "greater")
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p
* <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 len   OJ     VC        30    30      576. 0.0322
```

```
> calculate_pval(df, supp, "len")
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 len   OJ     VC        30    30      576. 0.0645
```

```
> calculate_pval(df, supp, "len", alternative = "greater")
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 len   OJ     VC        30    30      576. 0.0645
```

Am I getting something wrong about ellipse (although I have used it multiple times), or is there an inherent problem with the way I implement it inside a map_df function?

Comment: whcih package has `wilcon_test`? Also why you looping over `yvars` you have more than one?

Comment: "rstatix" package, sorry for not mentioning it. I intend to use more than one yvar, here for the sake of shortening I demonstrated only one.

Comment: simple, change `~` in the last line to `\(.x)` This is an issue with lambda functions generated by `as_mapper`

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I couldn't find too much info online on this issue, would love if you could attach a source or elaborate a bit.